# Why self made compare is working when I return object1-object2

Tags: java, compare

I would like to understand why o2 - o1 returns me a sort list I do not understand the logic behind it.
It is a method that I did but I can not figure it out why this o2-o1 sort my ArrayList.

I tried to look over the internet but did not find any answer.

```
    ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    array.add(1);
    array.add(3);
    array.add(2);
    array.add(5);
    array.add(4);
    array.add(6);
    array.sort(new Comparator<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return o2 - o1;
        }
    });
    for (int s : array) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

Comment: A comparator must return a negative number if the first argument is lower, zero if the two arguments are equal, and a positive number if the first argument is higher. If you have `(2, 3)` then 2 - 3 = -1, so this is correct as the 1st is lower. If you have `(2, 2)`, 2 - 2 = 0, so this is correct, as they are equal. If you have `(3, 2)`, 3 - 2 = 1, so this is correc as the 1st is larger. So, for simple integers, subtraction is sufficient to fulfill the contract (though it can be subject to underflow!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ArrayList` inherits [`sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#sort(java.util.Comparator)) from `List`. It expects a `Comparator` that can compare list entries via its [`compare`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#compare(T,T)) method. The JavaDoc for `compare` says:

> Compares its two arguments for order. Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

That's what your code does. `o2 - o1` auto-unboxes the `Integer` instances to `int` and then subtracts the `o1` value from the `o2` value. That results in a negative integer if `o1` is greater than `o2`, zero if they're the same value, or a positive integer if `o1` is lesser than `o2`.

`sort` calls the comparator's `compare` repeatedly with pairs of values, and uses those return values to sort the list.